# ordering by multiply columns pandas - 'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have the dataframe '**rankedvariableslist**', with the index 'Sleepvariables' being the sleep variable of interest, and the two columns being the R-squared and P-value of that model and variable respectively.

I am trying to sort the data in ascending order by 'P-value', then by 'R-squared value', but I keep getting the error: '**'values' is not ordered, please explicitly specify the categories order by passing in a categories argument**' and am not sure why.

I would be so grateful for a helping hand!

```
correspondantsleepvariable = []
correspondantpvalue = []
correspondantpvalue = [] 

newerresults = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary.tables[0]
newerdata = pd.DataFrame(newerresults)
rsquaredvalue = newerdata.iloc[0,3]
rsquaredvalues.append(rsquaredvalue)
modelpvalues = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary.tables[1]
newerdatavalues = pd.DataFrame(modelpvalues)
pvalue = newerdatavalues.iloc[12,4]
correspondantpvalue.append(pvalue)
correspondantsleepvariable.append(sleepvariable[i])
rankedvariableslist.sort_values(['P-value','R-squared value'],ascending = [True, False])
print(rankedvariableslist.head(3)

                         Sleepvariables  R-squared value P-value
0                        hours_of_sleep           0.026   0.491
1              frequency_of_alarm_usage           0.026   0.681
2                        sleepiness_bed           0.026   0.413
```

```
As an example of the dataframe 'newerresults':

                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:               distance   R-squared:                       0.028
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.016
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     2.338
Date:                Fri, 18 Nov 2022   Prob (F-statistic):            0.00773
Time:                        12:39:29   Log-Likelihood:                -1274.1
No. Observations:                 907   AIC:                             2572.
Df Residuals:                     895   BIC:                             2630.
Df Model:                          11                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
```

Comment: a little experiment. Use this before sorting: `df['R-squared value'] = df['R-squared value'].astype('category').cat.as_ordered()`
then
`df['P-value'] = df['P-value'].astype('category').cat.as_ordered()`

Comment: sadly, that does not order the categories either... when I print df['R-squared value] - I get: Sleepvariables
hours_of_sleep                            0.026
frequency_of_alarm_usage                  0.026
sleepiness_bed                            0.026
sleepiness_waking                         0.025
sleep_quality                             0.030
nap_duration_mins                         0.026. Thus it doesn't seem to be ordering the categories as it should... :(

Comment: When I enter just the line: "rankedvariableslist[['Value']].sort_values(by=['P-value','R-squared value'],ascending = [True,False],inplace=True)", I get an error message: KeyError: 'P-value'. Why might this be?

Comment: Are you sure all values ​​are float or int in R-squared value and P-value columns ?

Comment: try: `df['Sleepvariables'] = df['Sleepvariables'].astype('category').cat.as_ordered()`

Comment: when I tried to convert to float, I got this error: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Cell'

Comment: when I add in the line you suggested above, it doesn't give me any errors but is still not ordered :( not sure why

Comment: Can you write the code you are trying to convert to float?

Comment: rankedvariableslist['R-squared value'] = rankedvariableslist['R-squared value'].astype(float) :)

Comment: rankedvariableslist['P-value'] = rankedvariableslist['P-value'].astype(float)

Comment: I think this is an error from the dataset. Can you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37286844/typeerror-float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-when-reading-a-list):

Comment: 0        0.026
1        0.026
2        0.026
3        0.025
4        0.030
5        0.026
6        0.026
7        0.026
8        0.026
9        0.034
10       0.026
11       0.027
12       0.026
13       0.026
14       0.025
15       0.026
16       0.025
17       0.026
18       0.026
19       0.026
20       0.028

Comment: I have tried printing rankedvariableslist['R-squared value'] and I'm not sure how to convert these values to float?

Comment: I have amended the code above to show where the values came from earlier on - could there be something wrong with the way I have stored the output of previous variables etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74491328/float-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-cell-cannot-solve-issue - please see my new thread!

Comment: don't need this. I did the same operations with another dataset. As a result, you are making the first mistake when converting the model to a dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51734180/converting-statsmodels-summary-object-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I have now found a solution! Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked - instead of converting the model summary output to a dataframe, I converted the model summary output to a html file).

```
correspondantsleepvariable = []
correspondantpvalue = []
correspondantpvalue = [] 

results_as_html = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary.tables[0].as_html()
datehere = pd.read_html(results_as_html, header=None, index_col=None)[0]
rsquaredvalue = datehere.iloc[0,3]
rsquaredvalue.astype(float)
rsquaredvalues.append(rsquaredvalue)
results_as_html = resultmodeldistancevariation2sleepsummary.tables[1].as_html()
datehere = pd.read_html(results_as_html, header=0, index_col=0)[0]
pvalue = datehere.iloc[11,3]
pvalue.astype(float)
correspondantpvalue.append(pvalue)
correspondantsleepvariable.append(sleepvariable[i])
rankedvariableslist = 
pd.DataFrame({'Sleepvariables':correspondantsleepvariable, 'R-squared value':rsquaredvalues,'P-value':correspondantpvalue})
rankedvariableslist.sort_values(by=['P-value','R-squared value'],ascending = [True,False],inplace=True)
print(rankedvariableslist)

Sleepvariables  R-squared value  P-value
9    time_spent_awake_during_night_mins            0.034    0.005
4                         sleep_quality            0.030    0.041
20          sleepiness_resolution_index            0.028    0.129
```

Thanks so much for all your help - I am so grateful!